# helm chart - airflow version upgrade

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm

I've installed airflow on my k8s using helm chart apache-airflow/airflow.

Currently installed airflow version is `2.2.4`, what path should be followed from the options below to upgrade airflow version `2.3.0`.

1. The official helm chart version is `1.5.0` and the default airflow version is `2.2.4`. When the newer version of helm chart is released, the default airflow version will be set to `2.3.0`. Will the `helm repo update` and `helm upgrade` command provision the upgrade of airflow? or are there any other similar process or official upgrade process guide?
2. If the upgrade process to accommodate the airflow default version has to be manual, what process/steps should be followed? N.B. changing defaultAirflowTag value from 2.2.3->2.3.0 in values.yaml is not an option as it causes an exception.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved :
helm upgrade --install actually works. but I saw a message on airflow web saying some of data migration failed cause of schema changes in airflow 2.3.0. After I drop the mentioned table in postgresql, airflow worked fine.

and changing values.yaml also works.

```
images:
  airflow:
    repository: apache-airflow/airflow
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Answer (score 0):

there. I checked my airflow environment on my aws ec2.
It didn't work properly.
So I did lots of methods. It proved all failed.
But finally I found solution.

if you should run below these two commands, you should remove your airflow namespace first.
There is some errors in airflow namespace.
So I found that it worked properly after deleting airflow namespace.

1)kubectl delete namespace airflow

2)helm repo remove apache-airflow https://airflow.apache.org

helm repo add apache-airflow https://airflow.apache.org

3)You should see your brand-new airflow interface.

Comment: As it is currently written, your answer is unclear if the process you have provided actually upgrades airflow, or if just removes existing implementation and replacing with a new implementation (teardown & rebuild). Based on the original question, it sounds like the OP is asking for an in place upgrade process. Advise that you clarify your answer and then add a comment to OP and clarify if this is a sufficient process.

Comment: You'are right. My answer is unclear. So I find another solution. 

If you use apache-airflow helm chart repo, you could upgrade your repo. 

helm repo update apache-airflow

Try it. and tell me how it works.